# Changing text color in c-shell

Tags: shell-script, prompt, tcsh, csh

I can change the text color in the terminal permanently by adding this:

```
export PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m"
```

to the `.bashrc` file.

Now I have to go into cshell, what is the corresponding way?

Comment: Are you using `csh` or `tcsh`?

Comment: csh is the shell taht I am using.

Comment: I'm not sure that `csh` supports colors, does Anthon's solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the prompt is done with:

```
set prompt="some string"
```

in your case you need to notify `csh` that certain elements have zero width by enclosing them in `{%` and `%}`:

```
set prompt="\n%{\e[0;31m%}\[`whoami`\@`hostname -s` $PWD:t\]$ %{\e[m%}"
```

You can find some more info and comparison of  in this [table](http://www.understudy.net/custom.html#table1), on that page you also find some info on the various colours.

The C-shell (both `csh` and `tcsh`) equivalent of `.bashrc` is `.cshrc`. Create it, if it doesn't exist, and add that line to it.

Comment: These don't work for me on `csh` (they do for `tcsh`), I also get this error: `CWD: Undefined variable.`

Comment: @terdon, I fixed the obvious errors, but I don't have a real csh installed to test.

Comment: I've never used `csh` but I have it installed and none of the examples I find online allow me to color the prompt. They, like yours, actually print instead of interpreting the escape codes. Perhaps this is not possible on pure `csh`.

Comment: @terdon It's been 25+ years for me since I actively used it, after that `tcsh` and then `bash`. Could be that the `\e` has to be octal ( `\033` ), now I am not sure anymore.